# Is there any way to check which monitor is the primary display, then execute a command based off of that in windows command line?

Tags: windows, cmd, nircmd

I'm using nircmd to change my primary display between my first and second monitor by using two batch files on my desktop; one to set primary display to the first monitor, and the other to set primary display to the second.

I was wondering if there was a way to check which display is the current primary display and then based off that result, change the display to the other one. In essence, I want to combine the two batch files into one so that I can switch displays with one file.

Comment: Quick way - In your batch create a file when you switch to display 1, delete it when you switch to 2.  IF EXISTS will tell you if it exists in which case you know #1 is the primary.

Comment: Fantastic work around, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Alex K.
If anyone else wanted to do something like this, here's what the code looks like (I'm sure there's a better way to do it).

I just created a folder that holds the empty text file that determines which monitor is the current primary display. FILEPATH is the path to that folder.

`IF EXIST FILEPATH\test.txt (
    nircmd.exe setprimarydisplay 2
    cd c:\\
    cd FILEPATH
    del test.txt
) ELSE (
    nircmd.exe setprimarydisplay 1
    cd c:\\
    cd FILEPATH
    echo.> test.txt
)`

If anyone else stumbles upon this, feel free to ask for specifics.

Answer (score 1):

Combine [nircmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) with [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and you get this clean and simple script:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

primary_num := MonitorGetPrimary()

if primary_num = 1
{
    RUN("C:\Apps\nircmd\nircmd.exe setprimarydisplay 2")
}
else
{
    RUN("C:\Apps\nircmd\nircmd.exe setprimarydisplay 1")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$flagFile = "N:\Apps_Portable\_CmdLineTools\nircmd-x64\MonSwitcher\monswitch.bin"

if (Test-Path $flagFile) {
    # Flag file exists, so switch to the other monitor
    & "N:\Apps_Portable\_CmdLineTools\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe" setprimarydisplay 2
    Remove-Item $flagFile
} else {
    # Flag file does not exist, switch to the first monitor
    & "N:\Apps_Portable\_CmdLineTools\nircmd-x64\nircmd.exe" setprimarydisplay 1
    New-Item -ItemType File -Path $flagFile -Force
}
```

Using the logic you have for making a file to check which state we are in (rather than simply querying which monitor is primary right now because I don't see a way to do that), I have made this PS1/Powershell script. I then created a desktop shortcut to run powershell with this script.